# Use yq to query the full path in dotted notation

Tags: yq

## Motivation

I have a simple docker-compose.yaml file which is of this structure

```
services:
  foo:
    image: docker.registry.url:version
  foo2:
    image: docker.registry.url2:version
  foo3:
    image: docker.registry.url3:version
```

And I can easly do:

### GET

```
yq '.services.foo.image' docker-compose.yaml
docker.registry.url:version
```

### SET

```
yq -i '.services.foo.image = "foo"' docker-compose.yaml
```

## Wish

I don't know how many services I'll have but I want to loop over all of them and fix the URL of the registry in case it comes from my registry and needs some updates.

Basically I would like to extract all keys in a way they can be used in a query again - similar to what is in the Motivation as an SET example.

```
yq <<magic command>> docker-compose.yaml
.services.foo.image .services.foo2.image .services.foo3.image
```

And using these keys I can then loop over it using:

```
for key in .asdf.asdf. .asdf.; do echo "Some query using $key"; done
```

## What I tried

```
yq '.services.*.image | path' docker-compose.yaml
- services
- foo
- image
- services
- foo2
- image
- services
- foo3
- image

yq '.services.*.image | path | .[-2]' docker-compose.yaml
foo
foo2
foo3
```

Maybe with some query and merging this can print the path in a way it can later be used for a query again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with the `path` filter; you just have to convert it to a dotpath:

```bash
yq eval '.services.*.image | path | "." + join(".")' docker-compose.yaml
```

```
.services.foo.image
.services.foo2.image
.services.foo3.image
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the output as expected?

```bash
yq '.services | to_entries | .[] | .key + " - " + .value.image' docker-compose.yaml
```

**Output**

```yaml
foo - docker.registry.url:version
foo2 - docker.registry.url2:version
foo3 - docker.registry.url3:version
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually quite happy with:

```
for key in $(yq '.services.*.image | path | .[-2]' docker-compose.yaml); do echo "$key - $(y
q ".services.$key.image" docker-compose.yaml)"; done
```

But is there some better concept?